# How do I make this div appear when hovering over text above it AND do an animation?

Tags: css, animation, hover

I  have been trying to do this animation I found for these down arrows I created.  What I want is for the person to mouse over the "More Details" text and then have these 3 down arrow-triangles appear below the text and do an animation.  I really have no idea how if I even have the HTML correct.  Someone please help.

```
    <a class="details" href="#scroll">More Details</a>
        <a href="#scroll">
            <div class="top-portion__arrows">
                <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span> 
                <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
                <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
            </div>
        </a>
   

    .details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 42.75%;
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-portion__arrows {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 50%;;
}

/*.top-portion__arrows*/ .top-portion__arrows--hide {
    display: none;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 7px solid orange;
    border-right: 7px solid orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -70px;
    
}

.details:hover + span .top-portion__arows--hide {
    display: block;
    animation: animate 1s ease;
}



@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-20px,-20px);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: .5;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(20px,20px);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will do what you want

```
<style>
/* Style The Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I put in the animation? I want each of those "links" to just be a down arrow?

Comment: Did you  even apply my code to your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
<!-- <a href="#scroll"> -->
    <a class="details" href="#scroll">More Details
        <div class="top-portion__arrows">
            <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span> 
            <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
            <span class="top-portion__arrows--hide"></span>
        </div>
    </a>

.details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 57.5%;
    left: 42.75%;
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
    font-size: 3rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top-portion__arrows {
    position: absolute;
    top: 120%;
    left: 50%;
}

.top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide {
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-bottom: 7px solid orange;
    border-right: 7px solid orange;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -70px;
    
}
a:hover .top-portion__arrows .top-portion__arrows--hide  {
     opacity: 1;
     animation: animate 1s ease;
 }

@keyframes animate {
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-20px,-20px);
    }
    50%{
        opacity: .5;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0px,0px);
    }
}
```